# How launch game when user press "start game" button on telegram bot?

Tags: telegram-bot

I create game with BotFather and send this game with "sendGame" function to user, but i not understand **how launch game when user press start button**?

From [API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#games):

*When this button is pressed, your bot gets a CallbackQuery with the game_short_name of the requested game.*

My bot gets this CallbackQuery, but what next step? 
I try send message with my game url (http://192.168.1.10/game.html - this game i can launch on pc or phone browser, work fine), but this not work inside telegram... 

Can somebody help? 

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, now i understand, need use "answerCallbackQuery" function with 2 arguments: "callback_query_id" and "url". After this function telegram try open my game, but i see empty white screen. Html game what i try launche https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589521(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Try launche html5 hello world page from this https://jamie.curle.io/html5-hello-world

Comment: Need use external address - https://(external ip:port)game.html, but still not working, see white screen...

Comment: Problem with my web server or html5 hello world page, coz when i change url param on https://tbot.xyz/math/ game start correct in telegram. Still try understand how run html5 page on telegram...

Comment: I have ubuntu mate apache web server on orange pi. But now i create virtual ubuntu 16.04 on vmware, install apache, create new bot and new game for this bot, and i have the same result, still cant launch html5 page...

Comment: After several days i do this! My problem coz i use self-signed certificate and when i try start this page in browser, i have security warning, and need accept this for show page. Bot work great, but telegram web view cant show warning and show white screen! When i add my crt file to keystore on my phone all works great, thanks all for help!

Answer (score 2):

When the button is pressed the ["callback_query"](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) is invoked.

Using [nodejs api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegram-bot-api) I'm sending the link to the game in this way:

```
bot.on("callback_query", function(callbackQuery) {
   bot.answerCallbackQuery(callbackQuery.id, gameLink, true, {url: gameLink});  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been experienced the same problem, game comes up with white black screen,

When I try to open it with telegram desktop, which launches the game in browsers, it returns an error about HTTPS.

So I try to send my game URL using HTTPS like `https://mygame.com` then it works