# Pyrogram: The provided reply markup for the game is empty (caused by "messages.SendMedia")

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I'm using pyrogram to send a html 5 game to my friends. I create a game call "popspike" from @botfather and this is [the link of my html 5 game](https://lmjaedentai.github.io/popspike/index.html). Image below is the game example without inline button. The button is auto generated by telegram and the button is not works to launch my html 5 game.

[image: User click the play button to start]

According to [discussion in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44112033/17067135) and the [documentation manual provided](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/bound-methods/CallbackQuery.answer?highlight=answer#:%7E:text=specify%20the%20URL%20that%20opens%20your%20game), we need to use `callback_query.answer(url="your website")` to open my html 5 game (popspike), so I create an inline button to callbakc the query data.

```py
@app.on_message(filters.command("popspike"))
async def start_command(client, message): #send game to user & inline button send callback query
    await message.reply_game('popspike'
   ,reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([[InlineKeyboardButton("Play popspike",callback_data='test',callback_game=CallbackGame())]])) #reply markup is the error
   
@app.on_callback_query()
async def openquery(client, callback_query): #show text "hello" and open my html 5 game through `url` para
    await callback_query.answer("Hello", show_alert=True, url='https://lmjaedentai.github.io/popspike')
```

But I met this error when I want to call this command `/popspike` to send my game to user, so I failed to send the game to user.

```py
Telegram says: [400 REPLY_MARKUP_GAME_EMPTY] - The provided reply markup for the game is empty (caused by "messages.SendMedia")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\dispatcher.py", line 222, in handler_worker
    await handler.callback(self.client, *args)
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\pyromod\listen\listen.py", line 93, in resolve_listener
    await self.user_callback(client, message, *args)
  File "d:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\telegram\main.py", line 118, in start_command
    await message.reply_game('popspike',reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([[InlineKeyboardButton("Play poxpspike",callback_data='test',callback_game=CallbackGame())]]))
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\types\messages_and_media\message.py", line 1633, in reply_game
    return await self._client.send_game(
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\bots\send_game.py", line 74, in send_game
    r = await self.send(
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\advanced\send.py", line 77, in send
    r = await self.session.send(
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\session\session.py", line 362, in send
    return await self._send(data, timeout=timeout)
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\session\session.py", line 332, in _send
    RPCError.raise_it(result, type(data))
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\errors\rpc_error.py", line 91, in raise_it
    raise getattr(
pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.ReplyMarkupGameEmpty: Telegram says: [400 REPLY_MARKUP_GAME_EMPTY] - The provided reply markup for the game is empty (caused by "messages.SendMedia")
```

I do provide `InlineKeyboardButton` in `send_game` but why Telegram says "reply markup for the game is empty" ?

I apologizes for the long question since I afraid you cant understand I want to ask. 
 Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback of the error? also try not passing `text` and `show_alert` to `callback_query.answer`, i.e. just `callback_query.answer(url=…)`. Finally, I recommend to also check out the [official Telgram docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#games) on games.

Comment: I have edited the question to show you the full error. I follow your instruction to remove `text` and `show alert` but it doesnt works for me. But thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this on the second paragraph:

```
@app.on_callback_query(filters.regex('test'))
async def openquery(client, callback_query): #show text "hello" and open my html 5 game through `url` para
    await callback_query.answer("Hello", show_alert=True, url='https://lmjaedentai.github.io/popspike')
```

Give the argument `filters.regex('test')` inside `@app.on_callback_query()`

Answer (score 1):

As per [the docs of `InlineKeyboardButton`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/InlineKeyboardButton)

> You must use exactly one of the optional fields.

So try removing `callback_data='test'` from the construction of the button.

---

**Edit:** More precisely, `send_game` will automatically add such a button to your message. You only need to manually attach a keyboard, if you want more than 1 button to be appended. In this case, the first button must be the one with `callback_game=CallbackGame()`.

Note that for this button, `callback_data` is *not* needed to be able to parse the resulting `CallbackQuery`. This is because `CallbackQuery.data` will not be present, but `CallbackQuery.game_short_name` will.

The corresponding explanations from the [official Telegram docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#games):

> - If you send the game message without any buttons, it will automatically have a 'Play *GameName*' button. When this button is pressed, your bot gets a CallbackQuery with the *game_short_name* of the requested game. You provide the correct URL for this particular user and the app opens the game in the in-app browser.
> - You can manually add multiple buttons to your game message. Please note that the first button in the first row **must always** launch the game, using the field *callback_game* in `InlineKeyboardButton`. You can add extra buttons according to taste: e.g., for a description of the rules, or to open the game's official community.

Comment: But how can I send launch my html 5 game without `callback_data`? It's used to send callback query for `callback_query.answer("Hello", show_alert=True, url='https://lmjaedentai.github.io/popspike')` to open my html game

Comment: please see my edit